# Operand type clash: numeric(16,5) encrypted with (...) is incompatible with float

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm making the following query:

```
, case ur.column_1
when null then 
    case 
    when sign(quantity)+sign(TOTAL_GROSS_AMOUNT) + sign(TOTAL_NET_AMOUNT)>=0 then null
    else quantity
    end
else
    case(ur.COLUMN_2)
    when 'R' then 
        case (ur.column_6)
        when 'YES' then quantity
        when 'NO' then abs(quantity)
        end
    when 'L' then null
    end
end as RETURNS
```

It gives me the following error:

> Operand type clash: numeric(16,5) encrypted with (...) is incompatible with float

Does anyone have any idea where that comes from?

I should add that when I change the quantity/total_gross_amount/total_net_amount occurrences to just 1, it works fine.

Comment: `case ur.column_1
when null then` will never be true, because it evaluates to `ur.column1 = null`

Comment: @dnoeth good catch. Though it still gives me the same error even after changing it to case when ur.column1 is null.

Comment: Did you check this Q? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44182810/2527905 easily found when you copy your error message

Comment: Oh, I searched for the error message and couldn't find it. Much appreciated, thanks a lot !

Comment: @DaleK it does, thank you very much. I'll make an intermediary table to store the decrypted values so I can apply the operations on them when I want to load my target table.

Comment: I was just flagging it as a duplicate, I think there is a way you can confirm its a duplicate which links them together.